# Find Probability of m tosses until K heads

Tags: probability

Fix some k = 1, 2, 3, ...

Repeatedly toss a coin with probability of Heads P(H) = p, p is within the subset (0,1), until there are k heads in total. Let Y sub k equal number of tosses until the end of the game.

Find P(Y sub k = m) m = 1, 2, 3...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVO1V.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, obviously $\mathbb{P}(Y_k=m)=0$ for $m=1,\cdots,k-1$.  When $m\geq k$, we know that the only way for $Y_k=m$ to occur is for $k-1$ heads to show in the first $m-1$ tosses and the last toss to also show heads.  There are $\binom{m-1}{k-1}$ different ways for this to occur, each with probability $p^k(1-p)^{m-k}$.  Hence we have
$$\mathbb{P}(Y_k=m)=\binom{m-1}{k-1}p^k(1-p)^{m-k},\;\;\;m\geq k.$$